# How do I pass a static method to comp in clojure?

Tags: string, vector, clojure, integer

It seems as though I'm having problems accessing `Integer.parseInt` in comp.  I can access it normally like this:

```
user=> (Integer/parseInt "123")
123
```

But if I put it in comp, I get an error:

```
user=> (def vect-to-int (comp Integer/parseInt (partial apply str)))
java.lang.Exception: Unable to find static field: parseInt in class java.lang.Integer (NO_SOURCE_FILE:3)
```

It sounds to me like it's trying to find a field on Integer when it should be looking for a method.  How can I use `Integer.parseInt` like this?  And is there a better way to convert a vector of chars into an `int`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Clojure functions are java methods but java methods are not clojure functions** For instance Clojure functions have meta-data and such. If you want to use a java method where a Clojure function is called for then you have two choices in wrapping it up, `memfn` and `fun or #( )` memfn is an obsolete function that wrapped up a java method in a clojure function (its good to know it exists even if its not used often). The generally accepted way to wrap up java methods is:

```
#(. instance method arg1 argN)
```

or for static methods

```
#(Class/MethodName arg1 argN)
```

Comment: I guess the first line is not strictly true though it really gets the point across :)

Comment: I think you meant fn and not fun ?

Answer (score 7):

```
(def vec-to-int (comp #(Integer/parseInt %) (partial apply str)))
```

Or

```
(def vec-to-int #(Integer/parseInt (apply str %)))
```

`partial` and `comp` usually aren't as succinct in Clojure as using `#()` to make an anonymous fn.  Personally I'd write it this way:

```
(defn vec-to-int [x] (Integer/parseInt (apply str x)))
```

You can do this with plain `def`, but what do you gain using `def` instead of `defn`, really?  Using `def` obscures the fact that you're defining a function.  `defn` also sets up additional metadata for you (arglists) that `def` doesn't.

In any case, this is a more general way to do what you're doing:

```
(def vec-to-int #(bigint (apply str %)))
```

And still more general:

```
(def vec-to-int #(read-string (apply str %)))
```

Depends whether you want to be able to handle things other than Integers.